# PHP Email Form - Assign a variable to each input array

Tags: php

I am putting together a PHP mail based on input from a form.

On the actual form I have this for file inputs:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]">
```

For the email I am looking to have a label such as 'attached files' and then list all the uploaded files as urls.
example: If file1.jpg was uploaded, the output in the email would be www.myurl.co.uk/file1.jpg

Note the awful way I have tried to do this by setting $target_file1 for input 1 etc.
Apart from being awful code, the problem is if for example input 2 has no file, the email output will still show the first part of the url 'http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/'

What is the best way to take multiple file inputs and list them all as urls in an email?

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']); $i++) {
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
}

$target_file1 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][0]);
$target_file2 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][1]);
$target_file3 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][2]);
$target_file4 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][3]);
$target_file5 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][4]);
$target_file6 = "http://www.myurl.co.uk/uploads/" . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][5]);

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "test@test.com";
    $email_subject = "A customer has submitted their files";

    function died($error) {

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
      if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||  
        !isset($_POST['ref_no']) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }   
    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required 
    $ref_no = $_POST['ref_no']; // required 

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "A customer has submitted their files. Details are below.\n\n";   

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "RefNo: ".clean_string($ref_no)."\n\n";
    $email_message .= "Attached Files: \n".clean_string($target_file1)."\n\n".clean_string($target_file2)."\n\n".clean_string($target_file3)."\n\n".clean_string($target_file4)."\n\n".clean_string($target_file5)."; 

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
Your file(s) have been submitted successfully.
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to iterate the `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` and you are iterating one thing that isn't an array  (`$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']` the count() function doesn't returns all input files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way is upload all files, add in each iteration to an array the file uploaded, and then you'll obtain an array with all files uploaded (1 or 200, doesn't matter).

That code is an idea, don't copy&paste it.

```
  foreach($_FILES['fileToUpload'] as $key => $file) {
    move_uploaded_file(....);
    $array[] = $pathToFile;
  }

  $html = '';
  foreach($array as $singleFile) {
    $html .= "<a href="">http://www.yourdomain.com/".$singleFile."</a><br>";
  }
```

Comment: Does this deal with "if ... input ... has no file, the email output will still show the first part of the url"? If not, it should be easy to have a function that only appends to the array if the file exists. Though PHP was a long time ago.

Comment: The foreach iterate all files sended, if there are an input empty the input will not be send, so this code will be work perfectly according with the OP neededs.

Comment: Sweet! As I said, it's been ages since PHP, so I simply wasn't sure if the criteria was met.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this as the basis for my working solution.